# Asp.net file upload to a shared location

Tags: asp.net

I have this load balanced asp.net application which needs to upload files to a shared location. The web app is not impersonated, which means it will cross the machine boundry using network service credentials. Now my question is, to which account do I need to assign permissions on the folder where the files are being uploaded? How can I say the network service of these web servers need write permissions?

Comment: For IIS 6 it will be `[ServerName]$\NETWORK SERVICE` assuming you're using an Active Directory environment, otherwise see what loopedcode said about using the UNC and authentication.

Answer (score 1):

If your server is part of AD domain, then you can add the Server itself from the security permission dialog to have read/write permission (in fileshare server). Remember to select "Computers" when searching Active Directory. Depending on your setup, might have to search from the root of your Active Directory or select "Entire Directory". You will have to add all of your servers that are part of load-balanced ring to have permission in fileshare server's directory.

If your server is not within an AD domain, then your local server's network service will not have any security context to write on another server; which means only generic permission will work (e.g. giving write permission to "Everyone").

Otherwise you will have to use UNC authentication. An example is [posted here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/csharpgeneral/thread/0cbd77b7-5c6c-4a86-bc3a-e06eb888fa17).